# iterate through specific files using webHDFS in a bash script

Tags: bash, hdfs, webhdfs

I want to download specific files in a HDFS directory, with their names starting with "total_conn_data_". Since I've got many files I want to write a bash script.

Here's what I do:

```
myPatternFile="total_conn_data_*.csv"
for filename in `curl -i -X GET "https://knox.blabla/webhdfs/v1/path/to/the/directory/?OP=LISTSTATUS" -u username`; do
  curl -i -X GET "https://knox.blabla/webhdfs/v1/path/to/the/directory/$filename?OP=OPEN" -u username -L -o "./data/$filename" -k;
done
```

But it does not work since `curl -i -X GET "https://knox.blabla/webhdfs/v1/path/to/the/directory/?OP=LISTSTATUS" -u username` is sending back a json text and not file names.

How should I do? Thanks

Comment: You need to use WGET instead of curl i believe

Answer (score 0):

curl provides output in json format only. you will have to use other tools like jquery and sed to format that output and get the list of files.